# how to forcefully shut down physical server host through ILO?

Tags: vmware, vsphere

> I am new person of vmware environment i have shutdown a physical server through
>       RDP but it is not properly shutdown when i was checked in the ILO. Please suggest 
>       how to shutdown a physical server?

Answer (score 0):

To forcefully shut down a server host through iLO, you will first need to log into the blade system where the host is located. From there, click the host and in virtual power option, there should be an option to power off the blade.